# Create file in folder: permission denied

Tags: chmod, chown

I have a problem copying files to a directory on Ubuntu 12.04. I create a directory in the home directory so that the path where I want to copy to is:

```
/home/sixven/camp_sms/inputs
```

But when ini run the following command in the terminal to create a sample file as follows:

```
francisco-vergara@Francisco-Vergara:/home/sixven/camp_sms/inputs$ touch test_file.txt
touch: can not make `touch' on «test_file.txt»: permission denied
```

I can not copy files directly in that directory. How can I assign permissions with the `chown` & `chmod` commands to copy the files?

I do not know which user and group to use.

Comment: How did you create the directory? Why is it in `/home/sixven`? Why isn't it in your home directory?

Comment: From what you have copy-pasted, you are running touch as user `francisco-vergara`, but your directory is in `/home/sixven` is that really the home of user `francisco-vergera` or does it belong to a `sixven` user ? You should clarify what you want to do exactly. Write in another user's home ? Share that directory among a group ?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

First of all you have to know that the default permission of directories in Ubuntu is 644 which means you can't create a file in a directory you are not the owner.

you are trying as `user:francisco-vergara` to create a file in a directory `/home/sixven/camp_sms/inputs` which is owned by `user:sixven`.

**So how to solve this:**

1. You can either change the permission of the directory and enable others to create files inside.

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 777 /home/sixven/camp_sms/inputs
   ```

   This command will change the permission of the directory recursively and enable all other users to create/modify and delete files and directories inside.
2. You can change the owner ship of this directory and make `user:francisco-vergara` as the owner

   ```
   sudo chown -R francisco-vergara:francisco-vergara /home/sixven/camp_sms/inputs
   ```

   But like this the `user:sixven` can't write in this folder again and thus you  may moving in a circular infinite loop.

So i advise you to use Option 1.

Or if this directory will be accessed by both users you can do the following trick:

change ownership of the directory to `user:francisco-vergara` and keep the group owner `group:sixven`.

```
sudo chown -R francisco-vergara /home/sixven/camp_sms/inputs
```

Like that both users can still use the directory.

But as I said you before It's easiest and more efficient to **use option 1.**

Comment: Resurrecting this to say: you should almost never 'chmod -R 777' anything. Setting ownership correctly is a far safer practice.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions

http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777

Comment: The default permissions of a *directory* are normally 0755. 0644 is the default for regular files. Also, what @douglasAdams said.

Answer (score 14):

To change the file ownership, do this as root:

```
chown -R user:user /home/sixven
```

If you decide to go the chmod way:

If you know that the user is part of the group of the file

```
chmod -R g+rw /home/sixven
```

Otherwise:

```
chmod -R o+rw /home/sixven
```

But this way is not too secure.

Comment: Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

The default UMASK 022 (in Ubuntu ), so the permissions for /home/username becomes 755. and you logged in as user `francisco-vergara` and trying to creating files in user  sixyen Home: i.e. `/home/sixven`. it does not have write permission to Other users Only User/Group of `sixven` has write access.

if you want write access in that directory, then you need to be part of Group `sixven` using `usermod -G sixyen francisco-vergara`   OR `chmod -R 777 /home/sixven` (don't use it's bad practice ).

Comment: Aren't you rushing things a little? We still don't know the OP's situation.

Comment: Copy-pasters beware, `usermod -G` will remove you from all other groups (including sudo). Use `usermod -aG` to append a new group.